# check whether string palindrome

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ask the user for a string, and my text is Hello

```
text = str(input("text: "))
```

I want check whether string is palindrome:

```
def is_palindrome(a):
    if a == a[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

result = is_palindrome(text)
print result
```

I get NameError

Comment: Yes, and? What's wrong with your code?

Comment: SO what's the question?

Comment: Quick tip/pattern. You can simplify your code to `return text == text[::-1]`

Comment: `return text==text[::-1]`

Answer (score 3):

You named your parameter `text` but use `a`. For Python 2 use `raw_input` to input text:

```
def is_palindrome(text):
    return text == text[::-1]

text = raw_input("text: ")
result = is_palindrome(text)
print result
```

Comment: It's amazing how stuff like this still manages to slip past me.

Comment: and if I want ask user for a string like this  a  =  str(input("my string: ")) and then call the function is_palindrome(a)  I get nameError

Comment: @GagikKarapetyan: without knowing your whole code, nobody can say, why you get a NameError.

Comment: @Daniel I edit my code pls take a look

Comment: @GagikKarapetyan in Python 2.7 input is equivalent of eval(raw_input), thus if you enter something that is not statement it tries to be evaluated and returns NameError as it's not declared before. For Python 2.7 use rather raw_input instead of input, for Python 3 you can use input as it has same functionality as raw_input from Python 2.

Comment: @erhesto thanks bro now is working

Answer (score 0):

Your are not clear with what your question is. Okay considering that you are asking to check if the code is correct or not I am writing the code with little modification which will give you desired output.

```
def is_palindrome(a):
    return a==a[::-1]

s = is_palindrome("MALAYALAM")
print(s)
```

running above code in your IDE will give output as **True**. You can pass other strings to the function to check if given string is palindrome or not.

Happy coding :)

Comment: It's completely redundant to check for boolean value of something that already returns boolean. Please check Daniel's answer for more adequate example of such function.

Comment: I edited my code pls take look

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I edited my answer.

Comment: As @erhesto mentioned it is redundant to check boolean value of something if that just returns boolean. So try avoiding such redundant lines in code.

Comment: thanks @SrihariRaoM now is working

Comment: My pleasure dear :)